# Can I get the same object with its vales and use it in a different method?

Tags: java

New to the programming world and am even wondering if I am asking the question correctly so ill try to describe what I am doing as well as I can.

I have a user defined class/object that I put values into one method. can I then use those same values in another method? Every time I try and do this I either get stack overflow errors or null's for the values that I am putting in

```
private void foo(){
    Bar bar1 = new Bar("value"); //value sent to class Bar
}

private void viewBar(){
    System.out.println(bar1.toString());
}
```

I know that this is wrong because bar1 isn't defined in the method but this is what my mind is telling me to do. If I but bar1 in the class then i get a stack overflow and if I instantiate it again, it will show up null. Please help.

ok full program sort of*

```
private void enterGuest() {
    Guest guest1 = new Guest("bob", "arktor", "bob@arktor.com", Calendar.getInstance().getTime(), 5 , "suite");
    System.out.println(guest1.toString()); //overridden toString to show in nice format data
}

private void viewGuest() {
   Guest guest = new Guest(); // <--will give null(basically this but without the new) 
   System.out.println(guest.toString());  
}
```

globally i get a stack overflow, locally no other method sees it.

Comment: put your Bar bar1 outside as a global variable

Comment: Your bar1 variable is declared inside of `foo()` and thus its **scope**, its visibility, is limited to the `foo()` method. To get around this, make bar1 a field by declaring it in the class. Or even better, you could declare `foo()` to return Bar type and have it return bar1.

Comment: if i make it global i get a stack overflow, unless there is a global in java that I don't know about.

Comment: You have an error then in code you're not showing us. Please fix this by showing us the relevant code.

Comment: yay it works I pulled Guest out and didn't put Guest guest which was what I was doing, thank you so much.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your bar1 variable is declared inside of `foo()` and thus its **scope**, its visibility, is limited to the `foo()` method. To get around this, make bar1 a field by declaring it in the class. Or even better, you could declare `foo()` to return Bar type and have it return bar1.

```
private Bar foo() {
    return new Bar("value"); //value sent to class Bar
}
```

Much will depend of course in how you use the methods, in code that you've not yet shown us.

Comment: thank you soo much, honestly i think it was a case of i have been looking at the code too long